# What is the Migratiob path for repositories from gitlab 12.9. to gitlab 14.2?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api, gitlab-ce

I got a GitLab CE version 12.9.2 in a server A with almost 700 repositories, 150 users and a lot of groups (the projects are distributed in the groups).

This GitLab installation is using a remote  Postgres database V 10.
We want GitLab to upgrade to the latest CE version 14.2 in a new server, let's call it server B. This one doesn't have remote Postgres database.

Reading the documentation, I can't just make a backup and restore due to the different versions.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html

Neither can make a backup of the database and map server B to the database backup, because newer GitLab version require newer Postgres database.

I guess my only option is just to import the repos, users and groups 1 by 1, with probably  errors assigning projects to groups or user to groups.
We don't use runners or canvas or user stories. We just care for the projects, users and groups.

Do I have another option to make it easier to do the import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal upgrade path is:

- install the exact same GitLab 12.9.2 on server B
- backup the database on server A to server B
- upgrade on server B GitLab from 12.x to 13.x
- finally upgrade from 13.x to 14.x

That way, you don't have to import repositories/users one by one, and you don't skip major versions during the upgrade process (safer).

Comment: Thank u.. I will try the sugested path.. I was hoping to find an easier path

Comment: @YamilOrtega It is the safest path in my experience. Trying and jump over major releases when upgrading is asking for troubles.

Answer (score 1):

Migrating can be a bit tricky, especially across major versions like that. Generally speaking, it is not recommended to try to migrate across versions like that. You'd normally want to upgrade your instance if possible.

The import/export doesn't really support going to different minor versions (and this is especially true across major versions).

Your best bet would be to either upgrade your existing instance if possible, or clone your server to a new one (of the same version) and work on upgrading it there.

---

The upgrade path for GitLab to go from version 12.9 to 14.2 can be determined via https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/#upgrade-paths .

You'd also want to read on version specific information for the various versions so you know what changes are occurring and what to expect.

Comment: Thank u.. i Will try the path